# Built Ant with jar lib

Tags: java, ant

My dir:

```
root

------src

------lib

------------AbsoluteLayout.jar
```

I want to built a ant file with AbsoluteLayout.jar lib

My code:

```
<project name="TestAnt" basedir="." default="main">

<property name="src.dir"     value="src"/>

<property name="build.dir"   value="build"/>
<property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes"/>
<property name="jar.dir"     value="${build.dir}/jar"/>

<property name="main-class"  value="com.socket.ServerFrame"/>
<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
</target>

<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}"/>
</target>

<target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="build/jar/lib"/>
    <copy file="lib/AbsoluteLayout.jar" todir="build/jar/lib"/> 
    <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="lib/AbsoluteLayout.jar"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>

<target name="run" depends="jar">
    <java jar="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" fork="true"/>
</target>

<target name="clean-build" depends="clean,jar"/>

<target name="main" depends="clean,run"/>
```

But it does not work.

Comment: First of all, you can't embedded Jars within Jars (and have them work) without a lot of messing about with custom class loaders and other fun stuff.  Generally, instead, you add the Jar to the Jar's class path entry instead and then deploy them all

Comment: UPDATE: error msg: Error msg: org.netbean.lib.awtextra is not exit

Comment: Did you copy the main jar and the lib directory to where you're running it?